# How to install torchtext in cmake project on windows 10?

Tags: c++, cmake, torch, libtorch, torchtext

How to install torchtext in cmake project on windows 10?
Error:

```
CMake Error at X:\Programming\C++\Tests\TestPyTorch1\CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTorchText.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "TorchText", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "TorchText" with
  any of the following names:

    TorchTextConfig.cmake
    torchtext-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "TorchText" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "TorchText_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "TorchText" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

```
TestPyTorch1    X:\Programming\C++\Tests\TestPyTorch1   X:\Programming\C++\Tests\TestPyTorch1\CMakeLists.txt    11
```

Download via anaconda, build from github,

Comment: Yes, building the missing library sounds like a good idea. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem we can help you with. Maybe if you edited your question with whatever "doesn't work"...